# Flutter Widget Test wait for animation

Tags: animation, widget, widget-test-flutter

I have a widget test similar to:

```dart
testWidgets('Widget test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  provideMockedNetworkImages(() async {
    final widget = MyWidget();

    await WidgetTestFunctions.pumpWidgetTest(
      tester,
      widget,
    );

    // ....

    await tester.tap(find.byType(MyWidget));
    await tester.pump(new Duration(milliseconds: 3000));

    // ....

    expect(widget.value, myValue);
  });
});
```

And the following implementation of the on-tap method of the widget:

```dart
_onButtonPressed() async {      
  await animationController.forward();
  setState(() {
    // ...
    // Calls method that changes the widget value.
  });           
}
```

The problem that I have is that after calling the `animationController.forward()` method in the test the `setState` portion is not executed. How should I wait for this method to finish correctly? During the app runtime, this portion of the code is called correctly.

It seems like `await tester.pump(new Duration(milliseconds: 3000));` is not working correctly, the animation has a duration of 1500 milliseconds and as you can see the pump duration is double.

Comment: Did you found out what the answer was?

Comment: @SilkeNL not yet

Comment: Have you tried the pump without the duration? `await tester.tap(find.byType(MyWidget));
  await tester.pump(new Duration(milliseconds: 3000));`

Comment: I have had a similar problem where I couldn't find a widget after an `AnimationController.forward` call. I 'fixed' this by assigning a `ValueKey` to the widget I want to test, and then using that key to verify the info. This is not a solution, though, but more of a hack.

Comment: Hello @notarealgreal you still haven't found any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `await tester.pump(new Duration(milliseconds: 3000));`
try await `tester.pumpAndSettle();`

this type of pump wait for the animations end and then pump the frames.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and here is what was happening.

When you do

```dart
await animationController.forward();
```

You are not awaiting for a simple `Future<void>` to complete but a `TickerFuture` (extends `Future<void>`).

For some reason, in my tests, some of the `TickerFuture`s from the `animationController.forward()` weere cancelled.

In the doc of the [`TickerProvider`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/TickerFuture-class.html), it says:

> If the Ticker is disposed without being stopped, or if it is stopped with canceled set to true, then this Future will never complete.

> This class works like a normal Future, but has an additional property, orCancel, which returns a derivative Future that completes with an error if the Ticker that returned the TickerFuture was stopped with canceled set to true, or if it was disposed without being stopped.

> To run a callback when either this future resolves or when the ticker is canceled, use whenCompleteOrCancel.

Now, the issue with `whenCompleteOrCancel` is that it returns `void` (and not `Future<void>` so we cannot wait for it.

So here is what I have done (inspired by the implementation of `whenCompleteOrCancel`):

```dart
Future<void> thunk(dynamic value) {
  return;
}
final TickerFuture ticker = animationController.forward();
await ticker.onCancel.then(thunk, onError: thunk); // <- This resolves even if the ticker is canceled and the tests are not stuck anymore.
```